# django - what's the best ajax image loader for django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms, django-views

I'm using Django for one of my projects and would  like to load some pictures to the server using Ajax. 
I don't want to mess too much right now with JS and Ajax. I just need something that would nicely do the job for me of loading the pictures to the server or delete them from the server via Ajax.

Do you know of any good stable solution for that?

Comment: django-filebrowser is an admin app that allows you to easily upload multiple files at once. (It uses Uploadify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[django-imaging - Ajax driven gallery field for django admin](https://github.com/pielgrzym/django-imaging)